# Finding an ODE with specified solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this math problem: Find functions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ so that $y_1(x)=\sin x$ and $y_2=x*\sin x$ are solutions of the differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$.

I'm just so lost as to what to do.  I thought maybe if I could find a root with $\frac{(\ln(\sin{x})}{x}$ multiplicity of 2 then the second answer would be $(x)*\frac{(\ln(\sin{x})}{x})$ so if I put that into the general solution $y_1=C_1e^{r_1(x)}$ I would get just the $\sin x$.  So I solved it backwards with $(r-(\ln(\sin{x})/x))$ and ended up with the answer: $y''-\left({2\ln(\sin{x}))\over x}\right)y'+\left({\ln(\sin{x}\over x}\right)^2y=0$

I literally have no idea if that works... Help please!!

Comment: Look here for help to format. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

I went in to edit your question and the parts with $\ln(\sin)$ were so ambiguous I gave up.

Comment: Sorry! I guess I'm not used to formatting it for the internet I will try and fix it!

Comment: Thank you for helping me edit that!! So helpful! Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ such that $y_1(x)=sin(x)$ and $y_2(x)=x sin(x)$ are the solution of the following differential equation 
$$y''(x)+p(x)y'(x)+q(x)=0 \,\, (1)$$

By substituting $y_1(x)$ in equation (1), we have,
$$p(x) \cos (x)+q(x)-\sin (x)=0\,\, (2)$$

Similarly, by substituting $y_2(x)$ in equation (1), we have,
$$p(x) (\sin (x)+x \cos (x))+q(x)-x \sin (x)+2 \cos (x)=0\,\, (3)$$

And finally, by solving the system of equations (2) and (3) for $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, we find
$$p(x)=\frac{-2 cos(x) + sin(x) - x sin(x)}{-cos(x) + x cos(x) + sin(x)}$$
$$q(x)=\frac{2 cos^2(x) + sin^2(x)}{-cos(x) + x cos(x) + sin(x)}$$

Comment: So so helpful!!! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by starting with $y=a\sin x+bx\sin x$ and working backwards.  Start by multiplying by $\csc x$.

$$y\csc x=bx+a$$

Now we can simply differentiate twice to get

$$y''\csc x+2y'(\csc x)'+y(\csc x)''=0$$
$$y''\csc x-2y'\csc x\cot x+y(\csc x\cot^2x+\csc^3x)=0$$

Now simply multiply by $\sin x$ to get it in the proper form.

$$y''+(-2\cot x)y'+(\cot^2x+\csc^2x)y=0$$